# Custom Permission Level Using Powershell For Subsite

Tags: powershell, site-collection

I am doing the following using powershell.

I am creating a site collection with 4 subsites and 5 custom groups.

Site Collection : Parent
Child Site : One
Child Site : Two
Child Site : Three

There are four groups :

Group A, B, C, D

Access for the sites is as follows :

Child Site One : Group A, B, C, D (All groups have approve access)
Child Site Two : Group A, B, D  (All groups have approve access)
Child Site Three : Group A, B, C (All groups have approve access)

I am creating all this in a powershell script.

How do I set the groups permission in a powershell script for the sitecollection and subsite? I understand that on the front end I can select the group within the site and break inheritance and then "Remove the Permissions" and this removes the group from the child site. How do I do this in powershell as this needs to be scripted.

PS Child Site Three/ Two each have a group that have no access.

Answer (score 1):

To break inheritance on a site and give permissions to the groups you can use this code:

```
$web.BreakRoleInheritance($false)

$roleDefinition = $web.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions["Approve"]

$groupAssignmentA = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($groupA)
$groupAssignmentA.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition)
$web.RoleAssignments.Add(groupAssignmentA)

$groupAssignmentB = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($groupB)
$groupAssignmentB.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition)
$web.RoleAssignments.Add(groupAssignmentB)

$groupAssignmentC = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($groupC)
$groupAssignmentC.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition)
$web.RoleAssignments.Add(groupAssignmentC)

$web.Update();
```

Where $web is the subsite you want to give the permissions and $groupA, $groupB and $groupC an instance of the corresponding SPGroup.